# How to add image underneath title on title page?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, yaml, r-markdown

I am writing a data analysis report. On my cover page I want to insert an image underneath the title and above the author in the blank space.

My code is shown below.

```
    ---
    title: \vspace{1in}"Title"
    header-includes:
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    - \usepackage{titling}
    - \pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=3cm]{logo.png}\\[\bigskipamount]}
    - \posttitle{\end{center}}
    - \fancyfoot[C]{Insert Department Name Here}
    - \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
    author:
    - \vspace{4in}
    - \emph{Author}
    - \emph{optional Author 2 or contact information}
    date: \vspace{1in}\emph{Date}
    geometry: left=.5in,right=.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in
    mainfont: Times New Roman
    output: 
      pdf_document: 
        highlight: tango
        toc: true 
        toc_depth: 4
        number_sections: true
        fig_caption: true
        df_print: kable
    fontsize: 11pt
    ---
```

It generates the following output:

[image]

Since I've successfully added a logo, I tried placing a copy of the same lines into various places in my code, but I either get an error saying that it fails to compile (when I try to knit to a pdf) or the image does not show up.

Answer (score 3):

To keep it as easy as possible, just make use of `subtitle`:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: true
title: "Test"
subtitle: "\\includegraphics{unnamed.png}\\vspace{4in}"
author: "Martin \\vfill University of Duisburg-Essen \\newpage"
---
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason the subtitle is not showing up on my pdf. The code compiles, but no matter what I put in the subtitle (e.g. a string, an image), it doens't appear on the pdf output. Do I need to download some additional package to get the subtitle function to work?

Comment: Are you sure the indentations are correct? Are you still importing all the tex packages?

Comment: Ah yes. I figured out the issue; turns out it was conflicting with another stylistic element I had coded because I forgot to specify the vertical space. Thanks!